# jQuery overlay image within slideshow

Tags: jquery, image, overlay, slideshow, clickable

I'm just trying out to implement a slideshow like you find it on http://www.caffeuno.co.uk/

I have already a slideshow but what I need is the feature shown on this site:

Picture 1, wait a little bit, fade in the text, fade in the clickable button, wait up to 3 seconds, 
roll over picture 2, wait a little bit, fade in the text, fade in the clickable button, wait up to 3 seconds, 
roll over picture 3, and so on.

Can anyone assist in reproducing this? Would be great. Thanks for the spent time and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has the .animate() function that lets you animate the pictures and text fading in and out quite easily.

```
$('#image').animate({
    opacity: 1
}, 5000, function() {
    //Done fading, wait 3 seconds and display the next image
    setInterval(displayNextImage,3000);
});
```

See http://api.jquery.com/animate/ for more information.

You probably need to change the z-index of your divs that contain the image and text so that the one that is hidden (opacity 0) is greater than the current image before you animate the opacity to 1 using the above funcition.

I hope this helps!

Comment: thanks a lot. I'll give it a try tomorrow and come back afterwards.